# VS Code searching Python under Roaming instead of conda env: "The system cannot find the path specified"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda, vscode-debugger

I have the same repository checked out on the same branch to two different directories. Even using the same conda environment, I can run one in VS Code, but not the other. The `.vscode/settings.json` and `.vscode/launch.json` are identical between the two and there are no more files in the `.vscode` dirs. The VS Code version is too. The error message is

```
Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError
[WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\jpoppinga\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages'
```

(Looking at a stacktrace, this originates from `log.describe_environment()`, called from the Python module in the course of starting the debugger.)

The path does indeed not exist (`Roaming` does, but has no `Python`), but why is it searching there? It is supposed to use the Python from the conda environment, which it did up until Friday EOB. Come today (Monday), it tries to use a system-wide Python and fails.

I tried using different known good conda environments, but for this directory, they fail.

I also looked at the environment variables, although this seems pointless (since success does not depend on the conda environment, but only on the VS Code instance): No difference in which variable contains `Roaming` and which doesn't.

Comment: How do you specify the python environment? And how to execute the script to get the error message?

Comment: I'm using conda, which is well supported by VS Code. Normally (i.e. for all my other repositories still and the faulty one until recently) one chooses a Python interpreter from one of the available conda environments. This setting is no longer properly made or ignored or overwritten (or something else entirely).

Comment: Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it is trying to access a resource that is not there.
Make sure you are using the right python binary when executing your code.

The easiest way to do this is by pressing:

CTRL + SHIFT + P and then
in the search bar input: Python: Select interpreter

Choose the right path to your interpreter.

Comment: This is part of the mystery: Also I specified the same interpreter in both instances, one fails and one does not.

Comment: If you chose your local instance of python, then this makes no sense, but from the error itself, we can see that your python is pointing to: 'C:\\Users\\jpoppinga\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages'

If you aren't able to set your python interpreter properly, you can try reinstalling python, just in case something isn't right.

You can try executing python giving a full path to its executable, this should work even if vscode doesn't setup your interpreter as it should.

That would look something like:
C:\path\to\python3.exe some-python-script.py